# How to allow a Docker container to bind a privileged port as another user?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yaml` file where I override the user that is used to run the container process using the [user](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#user) directive:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
    front:
        image: "ghcr.io/hexil-org/hexer-front:latest"
        restart: "unless-stopped"
        user: "1002:1002"
```

In the container, a webserver needs to be opened on port `80`, however, this fails with the following error:

```
httpd: bind: Permission denied
```

From what I understand, this fails because `80` is a privileged port that cannot be opened by a user other than `root`. Is there any way to allow the user in the Docker container to open port `80`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the value of the `net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start` `sysctl` so that the container user is able to bind port 80. You would modify your `docker-compose.yml` file like this:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  front:
    image: "ghcr.io/hexil-org/hexer-front:latest"
    restart: "unless-stopped"
    user: "1002:1002"
    sysctl:
      net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start: 0
```

This will allow an unprivileged process to bind to all low numbered
ports.

Comment: This should also be set by default in Docker, so the OP may just need to upgrade.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me after upgrading my kernel from 3.10 to 5.4.

Comment: @Xxmarijnw it requires kernel>=4.11 https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/36560#issuecomment-1351710109